# Execute php script across sessions, requests and outside of scope

Tags: php, session, thread-safety

I'm developing some apis on my server using PHP. I have a script that makes a query on database and, after some logic on query result, it updates another table in database if needed. This script is executed every time there is a new request to a particular api.

My goal would be to set a boolean == true when the script starts and reset it to false when the script ends. So all new requests can read the boolean value and start script only if boolean == false. Otherwise the script won't be executed from this request and this is very good for my purpose.

I know that static variables in PHP maintain their value only in the current scope and session variables can be persistent only in the same session, but there should be a way to do this.

My first solution was to write and update the boolean value in a txt file on server (or on database) when the script starts/end and read it before starting the script. I haven't tested it, but if there are many requests, the txt file (or the database row) could be updated asynchronously from more requests at the same time, since while one request is setting to true the boolean value, another request could have already read this value and run script again.

Maybe instead of boolean i will save a date or a timestamp, so with some logic the script will be executed only if

```
(last execution timestamp + 5 minutes) < now()
```

Is there a solution to implement this?
Thanks

Comment: In computer science terms... The "read one table and update another" is the critical section. You want exclusive access to it. However, you do not want processes (sessions) to be blocked if they cannot access it. The issue is a race condition. PHP has a fix for this. See the flock function. You want to use the option LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB for exlcusive nonblocking lock.

Comment: It might be better to get a write lock directly on the MySQL tables (assuming you're using MySQL). See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/lock-tables.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use flock. In exclusive/nonblocking state, you can execute code if and only if your process has an exclusive lock.

```
$lock = fopen('/var/tmp/your.lock', 'a');
if (flock($lock, LOCK_EX|LOCK_NB)) {
  // Do your read/update stuff
  flock($lock, LOCK_UN); // Release the lock
}
```

This will avoid a race condition and give you exclusive access to read/write the data you need. However, EVERY script that is involved has to use the same lock file.

EDIT: Based on the comment below, I made sure to show that you need to release the lock.

Comment: Should i release lock with flock($lock, LOCK_UN) or this implementation release file itself?

Comment: Yes! If you don't release the lock, nobody else can use it. Editing the answer now...